# Creating server management system in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, site

We recently had a breach in our network and many of the servers got locked up. No one had a list of servers or VM servers list to show all the servers with app name and app owners. I can just create a list with Server name, status (active or decom), APP association, etc.

Are there any good site or list template which can inspire my idea so that I dont have to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Trevor already answered, You have to create your own list(s) in order to keep track of your server inventory. We did the same kind of things, create list with following field

- Server Name
- Ip Address
- Description
- OS ( windows / linux etc)
- Server type ( Physical / VM or etc)
- Serial Number
- Hardware ( CPU, Ram, DISK[type of disk san/nas etc]) multiple columns
- Additional Software installed
- Application Installed (SQL / active directory / DC / exchange etc)
- Application associated ( server belongs to SharePoint[even has sql on it])
- Server Owner
- Application Owner (contact person)
- Status ( Active /de active)

You can add/remove as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Waqas for your input. I was on the right track then. Thanks for verifying. It's more like Asset Management System.

Answer (score 0):

I think "re-inventing" the wheel will be your best bet and quickest option. You would simply create a Custom List with the desired fields, such as a single line of text for server name, Person (People Picker) field for System Owner, choice column for Active/Decomm, and so forth.